# render script error after updating eclipse

Tags: adt, renderscript

I was using ADT v22.6.2. There is no problem for my render script code. After I upgrade to ADT 23.0.2, I got some compilation errors.

error: Compute kernel root() cannot have non-pointer parameters besides 'x' and 'y'. Parameter 'ycoord' is of type: 'uint32_t'  imagealign.rs

Does anybody have an idea how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer version of the RS toolchain enforce the names of the coordinates be "x" or "y".  The reason for this is to disambiguate with other possible future params.  To fix this simply rename 'ycoord' to 'y'.